# How to replace single word in string not replacing other with same chars

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
s = 'letter of letters'
for i in s.split(" "):
    if len(i) > 4:
        s = s.replace(i, i[::-1])
print s
```

But this prints "rettel of rettels" which means code replace all 'letter' in string, but i need to replace only by every word themself.
How it possible to chagne single word but not all in string? I need 'rettel of srettel'

Comment: Can you give the output you expect to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to collect all the modified words separately, instead of modifying the string in your loop:

```
words = s.split(' ')
results = []
for word in words:
    if len(word) > 4:
       results.append(word[::-1])
    else:
       results.append(word)

print(' '.join(results))
```